# Call to a member function addMessage() on null,

Tags: php, slim-3

I am trying to add slim flash message to be accessed with my controller
using Slim framework 3 & Twig, But I get the following error :

> Call to a member function addMessage() on null,
>   Buzz\Controllers\MailController::$flash in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\app\Controllers\MailController.php on line 63

```
   // bootfile.php
     <?php
      $container['MailController'] = function($container){ return new \Buzz\Controllers\MailController($container); };                                                                                                                                        
       $container['flash'] = function($container){   return new \Slim\Flash\Messages; };
       $container['view'] = function($container){
        $twig = new \Slim\Views\Twig(__DIR__ . '/../pages/views', [  'cache' => false, ]);
        $twig->addExtension(new \Slim\Views\TwigExtension( $container->router,  $container->request->getUri()));
        $view->getEnvironment()->addGlobal('flash', $container->flash);
        return $twig;
     };

    // MailController.php
     public function sendmail($request, $response){
         $sent = mail->send();
         if ($sent) {
                     $this->flash->addMessage('mailsuccess', 'Thank you for contacting');
         }
     }
```

Comment: ```$this->flash``` is not existing i think so i guess ```\Slim\Flash\Messages``` is empty or something like this

Comment: `$this->get('flash')->addM...`

Comment: Thank you, but I tried to instantiate slim flash throught my MailController and create protected flash property, the error  disappeared but no expected result to my page